# Scheduling search parameters in FHIR

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I see FHIR documentation [here](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/schedule.html#search) mentions search parameters. Are all these parameters mandatory when user client sends the request for searching Schedules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No search parameters are mandatory and it's also possible to define your own search parameters.  In theory, the search parameters defined on a resource should meet the 80% rule, meaning they are ones most existing systems would currently support, though that's probably not true of all of them.  (We haven't been as rigorous about pruning search parameters as we have resource data elements.)  A server declares which search parameters it supports using the Conformance resource.

Comment: In the response of search query say search query for slots, is it ok if I set schedule reference to null i.e do not set schedule?

Comment: Slot.schedule is 1..1, so the intent is "no".  There are work-arounds, but it's best to adhere to the spirit of the spec.  Suggest posting this as a separate question and providing an explanation of why you don't have a Schedule.

Comment: sure, I have posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572294/fhir-search-slots-request

Comment: Hi Lloyd, Can you please let me know if the search slot request that I posted in that other question looks good ? Its here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572294/fhir-search-slots-request

Comment: I've asked the appropriate person to respond and poked him a couple of times.  You should be hearing soon.

Comment: Lloyd, Thanks a ton :)