# FHIR Search Slots request

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I am implementing FHIR server and for some un-avoidable reason I do not have access to doctor's schedule, however, I have access to the slots available for appointment booking.

I can get slots from 4 parameters using

> 1. doctor id
> 2. organization id
> 3. location id
> 4. date of slot

Will below be considered as valid slot query using FHIR :

http://localhost:8080/context/fhir/Slot?practitioner=Practitioner/123456789&organization=Organization/1234&location=Location/2&start=2016-07-25

Also, in the response to above query, since reference to Schedule is absolutely necessary (Slot has card=1..1 for Schedule reference), can I pass reference value as something like :

```
"schedule": {
    "reference": "Schedule/notrequired"
  }
```

in Slot response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now, you do have to expose a Schedule, but there isn't any reason it has to be "real".  The way we have currently implemented Slot searching is by exposing a dummy Schedule with the only data element being the link to the actor.  For example:

```
<Schedule xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
<id value="1234" />
<actor>
    <display value="Cooper Thompson, MD" />
    <reference value="http://host/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Practitioner/1234" />
</actor>
```

Our Slot search ends up looking like this (with some edits for brevity and clarity, specifically around the slottype):

```
http://host/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Slot?Schedule.actor:Practitioner=1234&Schedule.actor:Patient=5678&slottype=urn:oid:1.2.3|Cardiology&start=2016-07-21
```

Note that this is *technically* invalid, as a Slot can only have one Schedule, and we are including multiple chained search parameters for Schedule.  We also make use of extensions to send back the patient, practitioner, and location associated with the slot, since Slot.schedule is 1:1.  However this "intentional misuse" is the best option I've found without forcing the client to become the scheduling system and deal with lining up slots for each resource.

There are some tracker items ([9989](http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=9989&start=0), [9208](http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=9208&start=0)) in the FHIR gforge about making updates to Slot to be more friendly to "simple clients".  We'd appreciate your input :).

Comment: Thant makes send...one question regarding the mentioned url, how are you parsing Schedule.actor:Practitioner & Schedule.actor:Patient=5678 parameters at server side ? Don't they translate to URL like http://host/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Slot?actor=1234&actor=5678&slottype=urn:oid:1.2.3|Cardiology&start=2016-07-21 i.e URL having same parameter name "actor"
?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855829/fhir-new-patient-appointment-booking-no-patient-yet-created-in-system

Comment: There isn't really the URL involved in the context of these search parameters.  We just look at the value "1234" as the Pracitioner ID.  Similarly with patient.  We assume/require that the IDs that are used for searching are our server IDs.  Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Got it, one more query, so for that query, are you searching for appointments only on "2016-07-21" or also after "2016-07-21" ?

Comment: Normally for searching for "on or after" a date you'd do &start=ge2016-07-21.  See http://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html#date.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but not sure how you are defining the difference between the slot and schedule?

The Schedule resource simply defines a period of time that slots may exist within, and for which other resource. It does not define or expose the appointments that may exist during this time.

The [slot search parameters](http://hl7.org/fhir/slot.html#search) do not define any search parameters as you've implied. These are all on the schedule resource that it links from.

A Practitioner, Location and Patient can each have their own schedule/slots and thus it depends on the system where the complexity is defined.
Some systems decide that they are only going to worry about practitioners (who have their own room), others only worry about the room and will allocate practitioners later.

From my understanding of what I think you're trying to so (creating a FHIR Façade in front of a practice management system) I think you will need to expose the following resources:

- Practitioner: To expose the details of the practitioner (interested if your practitioners can work in multiple locations)
- Schedule: To simply expose the date range that you are accepting appointments (and will have slot availability defined) and the practitioner is linked to this resource, if they work at multiple locations, you'll have one of these for each location the practitioner works. (If the location resources have their own schedule, then will need to further consider it, and where the negotiation for available slots is done)
- Slot: To define the available slots that appointments could be scheduled into. (note: these are not appointments)
- Appointment: To receive the created appointments (Not sure how you're going to handle this if you don't have access to the schedule)
- Patient: Assuming that you want to assign patients to the appointments ;)

If this all makes sense and you clarify your environment, I'll put in the likely queries that you'll need to handle.

This was a great question, and Patient Administration is planning to write some implementation guidance on implementing this functionality in the various environments (General Practice, inpatient, outpatient, community, lab, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reponse Brian, I will shortly put the environment details here. Till then just one question - we are allowed to introduce additional parameter/s to any FHIR request right ? - provided we put those in server Conformance  statement ?

Comment: Hi Brian, I was assuming that schedule is nothing but the doctor's working hours, is that right ? Say a doctor working from 8 AM to 5 PM, then I was treating that time interval as schedule

Comment: In a way yes, and the slot defines actual specific instances on the schedule. Which references that schedule instance.

Comment: As for adding in extra parameters, doing this then reduces your interoperability without change. Which is what we are really looking for point and replace with better option. I still need to write the reference guidance on this with examples, happy to receive feedback on what you think is missing too.

Comment: Thanks, would like to explain environment. We have single login for any patient in any practice. So patient can go to http://example.com, select organization and login with creds to view records from our EHR. On same website, we publish doctors profile and their available slots based on users location choice. As we have 1 url for all practices (example.com) when we fetch doctor slots, we require doctor id, practice id, location id and date. Which means, even when we search doctor schedule, we require organization id and location id. Does that explain our env ? Let me know if any questions.

Comment: In above explanation, I am taking liberty of using practice & organization interchageably

Comment: Just had one more question, in Appointment resource, I see that it can have 0 or more references to Slots. Shouldn't there be exactly one slot reference for which appointment is to be booked ? If there is no slot coming in posted appointment (POST appointment request which takes complete Appointment resource as posted data) which is to be booked, how can it be booked ?

Comment: Not all systems have or use slots, and bot having it supports that. The receiving system could however check the schedule and allocate slots accordingly.  As for the can there be more than 1 slot, 2 reasons: Longer sessions that cover more than 1 slot (book a 30 min appt over 2 15 minutes slots) slots typically fixed length. And the other reason os if there were 2 schedules involved, drs and/or rooms

Comment: Ohk, now I get some idea of why is it that way, thanks. Also, after booking appointment, what should be the webservice response if I am using @create interaction from HAPI FHIR or for that matter in general if I am using create interaction ?

Comment: A create operation may return with an operationoutcome for errors, or the appointment that was stored, this will have the id that was allocated to the resource. Other servers may tweak the result such as replacing with validated slots if none were applied (none do this at the moment, but my server will soonish).