# FHIR New Patient Appointment booking (no patient yet created in system)

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

Suppose a new patient is trying to book an appointment using FHIR APIs , how should I get his/her first name, last name, dob, phone number in my system ?

The appointment resource just specifies actor reference which is an Id to Patient resource in this case. But I have not created the patient in system who is trying to book appointment first time. So I need all this patient details.

How can I post those details in Appointment resource which I post to create an appointment  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, if you do not wish to create the patient in your system yet until he/she shows up, the initial appointment could contain the Patient as a "contained resource": https://www.hl7.org/fhir/references.html#contained. This is useful for getting data across that doesn't have an identified endpoint on a FHIR server.

Comment: Yea, this makes sense too. Good to learn about this, however, I am trying to figure out how to use it for patient while posting Appointment resource to server. The syntax is giving hard time. Basically trying to figure out how should I replace actor reference for Patient in appointment resource with this.

Comment: Make the Appointment like this:

    <code>
      <Appointment xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
          <contained>
          <Patient>
             <id value="patA"/>
             <!-- patient data -->
          </Patient>
       </contained>
       <!-- appointment data -->
       <participant>
          <actor>
              <reference value="#patA" />
          </actor>
       </participant>
      </Appointment>
    </code>

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out to make code blocks in comments.

Comment: {
  "resourceType" : "Appointment", "contained" : {"resourceType" : "Patient", .......all pateint data goes here.......} ,                                                                     
   "participant" : {....participant data goes here}
  }]
}

Comment: Even i am unable to put in block comments, however, do you think above json for Appointment resource looks good ?

Comment: Three things: "contained" is an array (there can be multiple contained resources), so start with "contained: [".  


It's important that you have the "id": "patA" set under the "contained" node (as this is the local id of the contained patient), and then have the reference comparable to the xml example (so refer to that local id using "reference": "#patA").

There's a json example under here too: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/references.html#contained

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120612/discussion-between-ewout-kramer-and-comeongetit).

Answer (score 3):

You should expect to perform multiple FHIR interactions:

- POST a Patient resource to create the patient.  That will return the server ID of the patient.
- Perform a Slot search to retrieve the list of available appointment slots.  This will return a list of slots with their server IDs.
- POST an Appointment resource including the patient ID and selected slot ID returned from the first two interactions.

You may also need to perform a Practitioner or other search prior to creating the patient if you want (for example) indicate who the patient's PCP is.